# How can I create a tag in stack overflow?

Tags: support, tags

Is it possible to create my own `Tags` in Stack Overflow? If yes, how can I create tags, does it need a specified amount of reputation. I have seen the tag listings and in that screen creator for each tag, rename list etc is also shown.

Comment: It's possible. When your score will be big enough, at least above 1000

Comment: You can read below link, you need i guess 1500 reputation, http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: I don't see why this question should be down voted. Others might wonder/have wondered the same.

Comment: This requirement for needing 1500 rep points, before being allowed to create a new tag, seems crazy to me. (I tried to today, and got rejected with my mere 1100+).  So, meanwhile, would someone who DOES have the needed 1500 pts, please go evaluate the excellent tool called WikiView ( http://excosoft.com/blog/post/more-productive-with-wikiview/  ) and then go create the needed 'wikiview' tag, so that this tool can build up the following that it deserves?  Thx...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a bit more reputation, then give it a go!

Check out the rules regarding [new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). You can do it yourself when you get 1500 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).